# отправка пакетов с socket в сет интернет

Tags: python, сервер, websocket

Пытаюсь скинуть информацию на другой компьютер через интернет. Везде написано что необходимо просто указать статичный ip  `host = "192.168.0.1"` это хорошо работает если компьютеры находиться в одной подсети. Но что делать если компьютеры находиться в разных подсетях? а если они находятся по разные стороны интернета и у всех поднят NAT. ежу понятно что просто написать ip не не поможет. Не могу ничего найти по этой теме. Если есть статейки, поделитесь пожалуйста. пишу на python 3.9

Comment: Нужно на том маршрутизаторе, в подсеть которого отправляете, пробросить порт к нужному компу. Чтобы, например, при указании IP этого маршрутизатора и порта, допустим, 60000 Вы гарантированно попадали на 60000 порт нужного компа. Без проброса портов, насколько мне известно, через NAT не пробиться

Comment: Обратитесь к провайдерам обеих подсетей, и закажите белый IP - он будет доступен из вне и не будет изменяться.

Comment: Вариант белого IP, а дальше на роутере делать проброс портов. Другой вариант аренда сервера к которому будут подключаться оба клиента.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю за ответ